# In list with recent coments - only show one comment per page/post (latest comment)

Tags: comments

I am trying to make a custum 'Recent Comments' code for use in the sidebar. I have come a long way, but there is just one thing that doesn't do what I'd like it to do.

What I want is that, per page with comments that is found, only the last comment is shown. I was hoping post_per_page would do the trick, but it doesn't!

This is my code:

```
<?php

$args=array(
'author_email' => '',
'ID' => '',
'karma' => '',
'number' => 5,
'offset' => '',
'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
'order' => 'DESC',
'parent' => '',
'post_id' => '',
'post_author' => '',
'post_name' => '',
'post_parent' => '0',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_type' => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'status' => 'approve',
'type' => '',
'user_id' => '',
'search' => '',
'count' => false
);
$comments = get_comments($args);

foreach($comments as $comment) :

?>
<div style="border: 0px solid #000000; height: 1%; overflow: hidden;">
<div style="border: 0px solid #000000; float: left; width: 28%;">
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar(     $comment, 48 ); ?></a>
</div>
<div style="border: 0px solid #000000; float: right; width: 72%;">
<?php
$aantalcomments = get_comments_number( $comment->comment_post_ID );

?>  
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id); ?>"><?php echo($comment->comment_author) ?></a> op:<br>


<a href="<?php echo get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID); ?>">

<?php
echo($comment->post_name . " (" . $aantalcomments . ")<br>");
?>
</a>
<?php

echo get_comment_date(' l, j F, Y ', $comment->comment_ID);

?>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<?php



endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: What does happen?

Answer (score 0):

First you should KNOW all different posts with comments:

```
global $wpdb;

$SelectSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT `comment_post_ID` FROM {$wpdb->comments} LIMIT 0, 15";
$Rows      = $wpdb->get_results($SelectSQL);
```

then for each of these posts get the latest comment:

```
foreach($Rows as $row):
  $comment = get_comments(array('post_id'=>$row->comment_post_ID, 'number'=>1, 'status'=>'appprove'));
  $comment = $comment[0];

...
```

and continue with the display of comment, hope you are good at PHP ;) .

See also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: Well, I couldn't figure it out, but my brother, who IS REALLY GOOD in PHP did figure it out. He himself doesn't consider this the best of solution, but hey, it works. Maybe a quick-fix of which he isn't proud, but I am saved! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't figure it out, but my brother, who is REALLY GOOD at PHP did figure it out. He himself doesn't consider this the best of solution, but hey, it works. Maybe a quick-fix of which he isn't proud, but I am saved! ;-) He was even so kind as to comment his work. I hope someone else can use this as well!

```
<?php

$args=array(
    'author_email' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'karma' => '',
    'number' => 5,
    'offset' => '',
    'orderby' => 'comment_date_gmt',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '',
    'post_id' => '',
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_name' => '',
    'post_parent' => '0',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'status' => 'approve',
    'type' => '',
    'user_id' => '',
    'search' => '',
    'count' => false,
    'group' => 'post_id'
);
$comments = get_comments($args);

// Due to wordpress not having a common functionality, we create a new list of comments manually
$filteredComments = array();
// Posts we already have a comment for
$filteredUsedPosts = array();
// Amount of comments
$filteredCommentLimit = 5;

// Loop through all comments
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    // Have we reached our amount of coments, then weŕe finished
    if (count($filteredComments) < $filteredCommentLimit){
        // Do we already have comment for this post?
        if (!in_array($comment->comment_post_ID, $filteredUsedPosts)){
            // We add the POST ID to the list of used POST IDs
            $filteredUsedPosts[] = $comment->comment_post_ID;
            // We add our comment to the display comments list
            $filteredComments[] = $comment;
        }
    }
}

foreach($filteredComments as $comment) :

    ?>
<div style="border: 0px solid #000000; height: 1%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="border: 0px solid #000000; float: left; width: 28%;">
        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 48 ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 0px solid #000000; float: right; width: 72%;">
        <?php
        $aantalcomments = get_comments_number( $comment->comment_post_ID );

        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($comment->user_id); ?>"><?php echo($comment->comment_author) ?></a> op:<br>


        <a href="<?php echo get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID); ?>">

            <?php
            echo($comment->post_name . " (" . $aantalcomments . ")<br>");
            ?>
        </a>
        <?php

        echo get_comment_date(' l, j F, Y ', $comment->comment_ID);

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<?php



endforeach;

?>
```